# AngularJS ng-repeat in range not updating

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

First, I made an ajax call binding the data when the call returns

```
$scope.item = data;
$scope.$apply()
```

And I have a ng-repeat that does this

```
<li ng-repeat="n in range(item.length)" ng-class="{active: n ==currentPage}> {{n}} <li>
```

However the li element does not ever appear, any idea how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<li ng-repeat="i in item" ng-class="{active: $index === currentPage}">{{$index}}<li>
```

Comment: Sorry I've updated my question, can your method still work for my current requirement?